# Is there a simple proof that Milnor $K_2$ of a number field is torsion?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-k-theory

This is a theorem of Garland. I had a look at the original paper which looks pretty complicated. I was wondering if the proof has been simplified over the years or if a different approach is nowadays available.

Comment: Though I'm not at all a specialist in these matters, I wouldn't expect too much simplification: results of Garland and Tate have many connections to relatively deep theorems of number theory.   Anyway, Garland's paper is *A finiteness theorem for $K_2$ of a number field*, Ann. of Math. (2) 94 (1971), 534–548.  The Bourbaki Seminar report by Bass is freely available: http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=SB_1970-1971__13__233_0

Answer (score 1):

For a calculation of $K^M_2(K)$ for $K = \mathbf{Q}$, see Lemmermeyer, Reciprocity Laws, p. 66, Theorem 2.30. (Note that the direct product should be a direct sum.)